# MPI_TAG_UB for openmpi/2.1.1

Tags: tags, fortran, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to get the parameter MPI_TAG_UB for openmpi (I am using version 2.1.1). I know I need to use the routine MPI_COMM_GET_ATTR, but I have no idea how to do that, I never used Fortran in my life. Following this [link](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node369.htm) I tried this:

```
LOGICAL FLAG

INTEGER IERR

INTEGER (KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) VALUE

! Upon successful return, VALUE == 7 (sign extended)

CALL MPI_COMM_GET_ATTR(MPI_COMM_WORLD, KEYVAL, VALUE, FLAG, IERR)
```

I put that in a file `test.f90`, then did

```
gfortran test.f90 -o test.out
```

but I got this error message:

> Error: Parameter 'mpi_address_kind' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
>   Error: Unexpected end of file in 'test.f90'

So basically I have no idea what I'm doing. Did someone ever retrieve the value of MPI_TAG_UB for some MPI implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: Fortran doesn't know what `MPI_COMM_GET_ATTR` is - you need to `use` it. It looks like you should be consulting a beginner fortran book and then learning about how to use MPI in it.

Comment: I kindly say that you are in way over your head. Learning basic Fortran should be easy enough but MPI is not part of Fortran. You do not understand this because you tried to compile with gfortran. You would compile with an MPI wrapper compiler. MPI also has many requirements that are not explained in your link. You should first learn basic MPI implementations. Your question here on stack overflow is not appropriate because this is not a tutorial site. I suggest you find tutorials on Fortran and MPI.

Comment: The issue is not caused by using the compiler directly instead of a MPI wrapper. As @Ross already explained, you first need to `use mpi` (or `include 'mpif.h'` or `use mpi_f08`.